# lorentz model for light-matter interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter

In my Electro-Optic course we were trying to derive the electric response of dipoles in matter when exposed to EM waves using lorentz model for dielectrics. In the motion equation lorentz used, he placed a damping coefficient.
I have two questions, first: why did he introduce this coefficient, and what does it stand for exactly? if the incident wave frequency is not close to the resonance frequency will this coefficient change?

second: according to this model, atoms radiate even when the wave frequency doesn't resonate with the atoms, this explains why light is slower in matter, but whats the explanation on the quantum level? how do the atoms emit light if they are not absorbing it and getting excited?